# Control over external links after HTTP Post (cordova)

Tags: cordova, phonegap-plugins, hybrid-mobile-app, inappbrowser

This is my first hybrid app. I am in this for 6 months now, so i have gathered good experience. We target both android 4 + & ios 8,9. We are using `cordova cli`

In cordova application, we are currently developing a feature to pay online. We are using third party wallet system for that.

We prepare the details (unique id, transaction details, redirect url etc..) and post to the third party hosted server through HTTP post(not ajax)

Third party wallet system presented a page which allows user to enter the credentials. On successfull completion, user will be redirected to defined redirect url (which we will host in our server). In that page, there will be back button, on click he has to back to the app.

I tried the inappbrowser option, i was not able to get the reference of new payment page since it is post request not get (I mean., window.open is not helpful).  Please help me in this.

## Edited

To be more specific, In my app, i have form, it post to external url. In the external page, on click of link, i need to come back to my app.

Comment: HTTP to post to the payment system.. I would rather use HTTPS.

Comment: yes., you are correct., it is HTTPS.

Comment: Please **answer the following questions in your post**. Since this appears to be your first post on this subject. Is this your first hybrid App? What is your target platform and their target versions: Android 4,5,6? iOS 7,8,9? Are you using [CLI, SDK or Build](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#001) ? Please do not assume the answer, please read the link. Once you have answer the question *in the post*, respond in the comments so I know you have added information to the post.

Comment: You should also be aware that Phonegap is not a [webserver or a webbrowser](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005). And that both [Google and Apple frown on apps](https://github.com/jessemonroy650/top-phonegap-mistakes/blob/master/new-to-Phonegap.md#005a) that are website wrappers?

Comment: Yea, This is my first hybrid app, i am in this for 6 months now. So i have gathered good experience in that (If this is your question). We target both android 4 + & ios 8,9. We are using cordova cli.

Comment: Can you ask specific question. ?? So we can discuss over the problem.

Comment: See edited version of my question.

Comment: You first problem is *not following directions*. I ask you to put information in the post AND use my name in the post - otherwise I CANNOT see the comments. @kiran-syeed has your answer. If you stil have issues, use my name in the comments, then I can see your request.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650 Kiran-syeed's answer is not helping me, because, there is a form in my app. On submit, it will post to url. so 'window.Inappbrowser.open' is not helping me to get reference of the external page.

Comment: I'm looking at the details now. It may be a while. If I don't resond in 24 hours, please try me again.  In the meantime, see if this service has JSON or JSONP service. Thanks

Comment: @Saravanan I re-read the Original Post. It is not clear to me why the solution from kiran-syeed will not work. Simple close put a close button on the final page and that should close the inAppBrowser. Is there something else?

Comment: Thanks for your patience @JesseMonroy650. Solution will not work, because, I will not able to use window.Inappbrowser.open to get reference of new opened screen, since it is HTTP post to link from app.

Comment: @Saravanan You said that already. I will ask again, *is there something you are not telling me?* Because I know this will work.

Comment: @JesseMonroy650, How do you get the handle of new window if the request is POST, as we do for GET, var handle = window.open(url)

Comment: HAVE YOU TRIED WHAT I AM SUGGESTING?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105528/discussion-between-saravanan-and-jessemonroy650).

Comment: You cannot follow directions. You are not answering questions. End of conversation. Best of Luck.

Answer (score 0):

To come back to the app, you need to implement the following event handlers:

```
                var ref =cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, "_blank",'location=no,clearcache=yes,hardwareback=no,zoom=no');                    
                ref.addEventListener('loadstart',onBrowserLoadStart);
                ref.addEventListener('loadstop',onBrowserLoadStop);
                ref.addEventListener('loaderror', onBrowserError);
                ref.addEventListener('exit', onBrowserClose);
```

on Close button in the browser, redirect to some dummy close page and then on  onBrowserLoadStart event, do something like this:

```
             var cUrl= 'webpageaddress/dummytemplate/appClose';
             if(event.url===cUrl){
                  ref.close();
             }
```

To Post data to form , in external page. Do something like this:

```
        function onBrowserLoadStop(event){

//alert('form url is:'+ event.url);
var cUrl= 'externalPageAddress/Dummytemplate/PaymentProcess';
if(event.url===cUrl){

    var msg;
    var newHtml='someHTMLDATA';


    var withoutScriptHtml = $(newHtml.bold());
    withoutScriptHtml.find('script').remove();


    msg=    " var formDiv = document.createElement('div'); formDiv.id='paymentFormDiv'; ";
    msg+=   " formDiv.innerHTML='" + withoutScriptHtml.html()+ "';" ;
    msg +=  " document.getElementById('InputForm').appendChild(formDiv);";
    msg +=  " document.getElementById('paymentForm').submit();";



    ref.executeScript(
        {
            code: msg
        },
        function(values){
            console.log(JSON.stringify(values));
        }
    );


}
```

}

Comment: Yes., this will work if the endpoint is GET endpoint. But in my case, i need to form post to an endpoint.